# using statement with array - type must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays

The following code using the `using` statement was meant to avoid some sort of memory leak which renders the code slow over long files:

```
var db = new EntityContext();
var cubos = db.CubosTrabalhados;
var cubo = new CuboTrabalhado();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Files.cuboHistorico, Encoding.Default);
bool header = true;
int i = 2;

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (header) header = false;
    else
    {
        using (var reg = line.Split(';'))
        {
            cubo.Pedido = reg[0];
            cubo.DataPedido = Select.ParseDate(reg[3]);
            cubo.Cliente = reg[4];
            cubo.UF = Select.Uf(reg[5]);
            cubo.Cidade = reg[6];
            cubo.Regiao = reg[7];
            cubo.Codigo = reg[8];
            cubo.Produto = reg[9];
            ...
            cubo.VlCom = Select.ParseFloat(reg[63]);
            cubo.Cnpj = reg[64];
            cubo.CodProdOriginal = reg[65];

            cubos.Add(cubo);
            db.SaveChanges(); 
        }
    }
}
```

But the line with the `using` statement give the error:

> 'string[]': type used in a using statement must be implicitly
>   convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

As `Split` is regular part of .net I have no clue whatsoever how to implement of the `IDisposable` interface in such a case.

How does it work?

Comment: Just remove the `using`, there is no memory leak from splitting a string unless you save a reference to `reg` somewhere.

Comment: You don't need to dispose string arrays. That's the job of the garbage collector

Comment: `using` is completely useless in this context.

Comment: It's the *DbContext* that needs disposing in this case, not the string array.

Comment: It's slow because you're doing a write to the database for every lines. Put your db save changes outside of your for each loop. You already have `cubos` tracked.

Comment: This is obviously non-compiling code. Why post this, what was it originally?

Comment: The same without the "using"

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I guess the main reason the code was posted was to avoid being down-voted for asking why the code was causing a particular compiler error and not attaching the code that caused the error.

Comment: @SergioDiFiore: Do you have any reason to believe that a memory leak could be causing the code to become slow over long files? Does it start fast & slow down - or does it just appear to be slow because the file is big?

Comment: It started very fast, a fraction of second per register and takes almost 5 seconds per register when reached register around 100.000... The time increased with the number of register being processed

Comment: See the comment from 12seconds above and Tim's answer. I assume that db.SaveChanges() is saving the changes in "cubos" - which appears to be some form of list - increasing in size with each Add. When you have only got a few items then it is going to be quick to save the changes, by the time you get to 100000 it is going to be much slower & you do this each time you add another entry. Either move the SaveChanges to outside the foreach loop - or possibly have a counter & only save changes every 1000 (for example) adds.

Answer (score 8):

`Split` returns an `Array`, which doesn't implement `IDisposable`. You couldn't use `using` in such a case, what is more - you don't need to.

Answer (score 4):

You can only use the `using`-statement on types that implement `IDisposable`. A `string[]` doesn't implement it because strings are managed resources, so the garbage collector will clean up everything.

- So it's not necessary and doesn't compile if you try to use with an array. But you should always dispose the `EntityContext`, that really implements `IDisposable`.
- There's a another bug. You have only a single `CuboTrabalhado` instance because you declare it before the loop, you want to create one for every item in the `string[]`.
- You can call `SaveChanges` after  the loop to commit all changes, you don't need to do it inside

---

```
using(var db = new EntityContext())
{
    var cubos = db.CubosTrabalhados;
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Files.cuboHistorico, Encoding.Default);
    bool header = true;
    int i = 2;

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (header) header = false;
        else
        {
            var reg = line.Split(';');
            var cubo = new CuboTrabalhado();
            cubo.Pedido = reg[0];

            ...

            cubos.Add(cubo);
        }
    }
    db.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `using` statement is the executive part of the `IDisposable` interface and pattern.   Your error comes from `string[]` not being a class in the traditional sense, much less one that inherits from `IDisposable`.

`using` doesn't magically prevent memory leaks.  The way it prevents them is how it functions as syntactic sugar that makes code easier to read and maintain when using `IDisposable` objects that have unmanaged resources.  An example would be an `SqlCommand`.

```
using(var x = new SqlCommand("select gunk from someStuff", myDataConnection))
{
        x.Connection.Open();
        x.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

is the same as

```
var x = new SqlCommand("select gunk from someStuff", myDataConnection);
try
{
       x.Connection.Open();
       x.ExecuteQuery();
}
finally
{
      x.Connection.Close();
      x.Dispose(); 
}
```

As you can see, `using` is largely there so that you don't have to remember to close/dispose connections or objects, and makes their scope more clear in large blocks of code.

Your slow performance is probably because you're hammering `SaveChanges()` in your loop.  Call that method when you've completed the changes instead of during each iteration.